# Is it generally true that $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \mid \theta) = P(X_1 \mid \theta)\cdots P(X_n \mid \theta)$ if $X_i$'s are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Is it generally true that $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \mid \theta) = P(X_1 \mid \theta)\cdots P(X_n \mid \theta)$ if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent of each other?

I have tried to prove this but cannot get rid of the $\theta$. Is this usually taken as a definition? Thanks!

Comment: May we assume that $\theta$ and the $X_i$ are events?

Comment: Here I have them as random variables.

Comment: Then what does the $P$ stand for? Normally it is the probability of an event, otherwise you would use $E$ for expectation or you would speak about the probability (conditional or not) that the variables take their values in a certain set.

Comment: If they are random variables then what you wrote is not clear

Comment: Check out conditional independence. It is not in general the same as independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are events, this is not true.  Consider
tossing two  fair coins,  $X_1 = $ heads on the first coin,
$X_2 = $ heads on the second, $\theta = $ exactly one heads. Then $\mathbb P(X_1, X_2 | \theta) = 0$ but $\mathbb P(X_1 | \theta) =\mathbb P(X_2 | \theta) = 1/2$.  In terms of random variables (the indicators of those events), 
$$0 = \mathbb P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1 | \theta = 1)  \ne \mathbb P(X_1 = 1 | \theta = 1)\; \mathbb P(X_2 = 1 | \theta = 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally true.

That a series of random variables $\{X_i\}$ are mutually independent, is *no guarantee* that they remain mutually independent when conditioned on some other random variable.